# Parsing a specific element from XML using Python/ET

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I have XML along the following lines:

```
<?xml version="xxx"?>
<doc:document xmlns:doc="some value 1...">
    <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="some value 2...">
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="some value...">
            <dct:format xmlns:dct="http://someurl/">some value 3</dct:format>
            <dct:title xmlns:dct="http://someurl/">some text of interest to me</dct:title>
        </rdf:Description>
    </rdf:RDF>
</doc:document>
```

How do I get the "some text of interest to me" using Python/ETree?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to look for the `title` element by specifying the namespace:

```
tree.find('.//dct:title', namespaces={'dct': 'http://purl.org/dc/terms/'})
```

You *have* to pass in a `namespaces` mapping on each search, so you could also just specify that up front and reuse:

```
nsmap = {
    'dct': 'http://purl.org/dc/terms/',
    'doc': 'http://www.witbd.org/xmlns/common/document/',
    'rdf': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#',
}

tree.find('.//dct:title', namespaces=nsmap)
```

For your example document (with the namespaces restored), that gives:

```
>>> tree.find('.//dct:title', namespaces=nsmap)
<Element '{http://purl.org/dc/terms/}title' at 0x105ec4690>
>>> tree.find('.//dct:title', namespaces=nsmap).text
'some text of interest to me'
```

You could also use the namespace in an XPath expression:

```
tree.find('.//{http://purl.org/dc/terms/}title')
```

which is what using a prefix and the `namespaces` map does internally anyway.

Comment: BTW this method doesnt work when cElementTree is imported; only with ElementTree